# Finding source of Status_Stack_Buffer_Overrun

Tags: c++, memory, buffer

in my program I'm using a switch statement inside a while loop to produce a user menu. When running my first two options I have coded work fine and then take me back to the user menu. However when enter '9' the exit option I hit a breakpoint and get a message saying Status_Buffer_Overrun encountered. Being not too clued up on how memory allocation works I'm a bit confused as to what is causing this problem.

this is the code for my main.cpp file.

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include "twitcurl.h"
#include "curl/curl.h"
#include"classes.h"

FILE _iob[] = { *stdin, *stdout, *stderr };

extern "C" FILE * __cdecl __iob_func(void)
{
    return _iob;
}


void oauthLogin(twitCurl &twitterObj);
bool login(twitCurl&);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //make twitcurl instance
    twitCurl twitterObj;

    bool load = true;
    oauthLogin(twitterObj);
    load = login(twitterObj);
    if (load == false)
    {std::cout << "error." << std::endl; }
    else
    {
        user currentUser;
        currentUser.loadUserData(twitterObj);
        char menuChoice;
        //user is now logged in. Give them menus screen.
        do
        {

            std::cout << "1 - View your timeline.\n";
            std::cout << "2 - Send tweet.\n";
            std::cout << "3 - See Recommended Hashtags.\n";
            std::cout << "4 - See Degrees of separation.\n";
            std::cout << "9 - Exit. \n";
            std::cout << "Enter your choice and press return: "; std::cin >> menuChoice;

        } while (menuChoice != '9');
            switch (menuChoice)
            {
            case '1':

                currentUser.loadTimeline(twitterObj);
                break;

            case '2':

                currentUser.sendTweet(twitterObj);
                break;
            case'9':

                break;

            default:

                std::cout << "Pick a valid choice.\n" << std::endl;
                std::cout << "Please enter a valid choice." << std::endl;

                break;

               }
              }
return 0;
};
```

Comment: *However when enter '9' the exit option I hit a breakpoint and get a message saying Status_Buffer_Overrun encountered* -- That doesn't mean that the "9" option is the issue.  It could be choices 1 and/or 2.  Comment out those calls and see what happens.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, cheers for the reply man. I just tried what you suggested there and it still hit the same breakpoint as before. Also out of curiosity I tried commenting out the instance of the "user" class "currentUser" also the member function I called in the line right after that. I'm still getting the same issue :/

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Also tried .clear() on all my strings after use